# php extended class in namespace refactor

Tags: php

I have made a class inside a namespace which is working perfectly fine but I think  the code can be better. Right now I have to use a '/' for every object inside the class which is not the best thing to do I assume.

```
 namespace Classes{
    use Basic

    class Enemy extends Basic{
      // Constructor
      public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct("Enemy",  new \Defense("Block", ""), 60, [new \Attack("Punch", 50));
      }
    }
```

}

Is it possible to do something like this? So I dont have to use a '/' for every object but just for the class itself.

```
 namespace Classes{
    use Basic

    class Enemy extends \Basic{
      // Constructor
      public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct("Enemy",  new Defense("Block", ""), 60, [new Attack("Punch", 50));
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried to do some research on Google however the only thing I can find is: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_namespaces.asp and here is not explained how to do such thing.

Comment: You have a `use Basic;` so you don't need a backslash before it. Just do: `extends Basic`. Do the same with the Defence and Attach classes: `use Defense;` and `use Attack;` and then just do `Defense` and `Attack` in your code. When you add a class using `use SomeNamespace\ClassName;`, PHP imports that class so you can simply do `ClassName` without the backslash. You can read more [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: Btw, if you only have one class/namespace in a file, you can simply do: `namespace FooBar;` without the `{` and `}`. If you have multiple namespaces/classes in the same file, I would refactor the code to be one class/namesapce per file.

Comment: I used the backlash before it because if I try to do it without the backlash I get the error: Undefined type 'Classes\Defense'. The only way I got this working is with the backlash included,

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, you need to add `use Defense;` to be able to use that class without the backslash. That imports the class so you can use just `Defense` without the backslash. Read through the link I posted since it explains all this very well.

Comment: OH my bad. I did misread it and thought you meant to add the use Defense inside the class object. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My prefered way is this:

```
<?php

namespace Classes;

use Basic;
use Defense;
use Attack;

class Enemy extends Basic
{
    const WHAT_IS_THIS_NUMBER = 60;
    const ALSO_THIS_NUMBER = 50;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
            "Enemy",
            new Defense("Block", ""),
            self::WHAT_IS_THIS_NUMBER,
            new Attack("Punch", self::ALSO_THIS_NUMBER)
        );
    }
}
```

As usual, w3school had provided ugly and oldscholl code.